# String manipulation: I don't understand the use of str.length-1 in this coding challenge

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop

I am currently learning JS, and I am practicing with the help of coding challenges. There is one challenge where I don't get why str.length-1 is used. It's the -1 that is tricky to me. I get that str.length-1 is to get the last value of an array. But in the case of this challenge, I don't get it.

**The challenge**:
Have the function DashInsert(str) insert dashes ('-') between each two odd numbers in str. For example: if str is 454793 the output should be 4547-9-3. Don't count zero as an odd number.

**The answer**

```js
function DashInsert(str) { 

  let arr = str.split('');

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length-1; i++) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 !== 0 && arr[i+1] % 2 !== 0) {
      arr[i] = arr[i] + '-';
    }
  }
  
  return arr.join('');
         
}

DashInsert(prompt('Enter a sequence of numbers', 134866620));
```

Why is is str.length-1 and not str.length?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you think happens if you remove the `-1`? Try removing it and see what happens and does it match up with your expectation.

Comment: if the length is odd, you can ignore the last character because the dash cannot be one tail. if the length is even, the last character can also be ignore, so whatever the length is odd or even, we can always skip last character, that is why above solution uses `str.length -1` instead of `str.length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop has to iterate from the first character to the character just before the last one. It cannot go up to the last one- because the requirement is to put hyphen BETWEEN characters. The last hyphen is going to be placed before the last character (provided the last 2 are odd).

Let's take an example

```
999
```

If you need to put a hyphen between the characters, only 2 hyphens can fit.

```
9-9-9
```

You just have to go through the first two "9" charhacters to place the hyphen after each one. That is length-1.

Answer (score 0):

`string[index]` will get the character at that index. index is always zero based.

Consider this example.

```
String characters :  s t a c k o v e r f 

index                0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Length of `stackoverf` is 10 but if you try to get the element at 10th index it will get you undefined. So in your code `str.length-1` get you the last character of the string

```js
const str = 'stackoverf';
const x = str.length;
console.log(str[x]);
console.log(str[x - 1])
```